# Why do i have 2 times the same navbar instead of 2 different navbars in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

Today i present myself with another issue.
In my own wordpress theme i created 2 nav menus:
navbar_pc and navbar_mobile.
When i try to implement these 2 navbars, only the mobile one shows up in the source code.
here is the content of those files:
navbar_pc:

```
<nav>
<?php
    $argsforpcnavbar=array (
        "theme-location" => "nav_pc"
    );
        wp_nav_menu($argsforpcnavbar);

?>
</nav>
```

and navbar_mobile:

```
<nav>
    <?php
        $argsformobilenavbar=array (
            "theme-location" => "nav_mobile"
        );
            wp_nav_menu($argsformobilenavbar);

    ?>
</nav>
```

those are called in the header.php and registered as menus and
header.php

```
      <div class="allnavbars-wrapper">
        <?php get_template_part("template_parts/navbar_pc"); ?>
        <?php get_template_part("template_parts/navbar_mobile"); ?>
      </div>
```

in the functions.php they are registered as follows:

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'nav_pc' => __( 'Navigationsmenü für PCs' ),
      'nav_mobile' => __( 'Navigationsmenü für mobile Endgeräte' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

How can i solve this Issue? I assigned them both for their positions but either 2 times navbar_mobile shows up or only navbar_mobile shows up.
and of course the nav tags are closed below. dont worry about that.
navbar_pc only shows up when i remove navbar_mobile.

Thanks in Advance,

Your Alwin :)

Comment: _"and of course the nav tags are closed below."_ - below _what_? Each individual menu, or both of them? What is the point of writing that whole sentence, instead of just showing the `</nav>` tag in your code directly in place?

Comment: i added it. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this condition for both

```
if(wp_is_mobile()){
 //put the mobile menu code
}else{
// put the desktop menu code
}
```